# jQuery / javascript - trying to pass an object's function as a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have an adjustable height for separate columns based on different percentages compared to other users data.

```
function Person(name, points) {
    "use strict";
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
    this.height = 0;
}

var daniel = new Person('Daniel', '2');
var boaz = new Person('Boaz', '4');
var josh = new Person('josh', '5');

Person.prototype.getHeight = function () {
    "use strict";
    var scores = [daniel.height, boaz.height, josh.height],
        highest = 0,
        i = 0;
    for (i; i < scores.length; i += 1) {
        if (scores[i] > highest) {
            highest = scores[i];
        }
    }
    this.height = String(this.points / highest);
    return this.height;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    var $daniel = daniel.getHeight() + '%',
        $boaz = boaz.getHeigt() + '%',
        $josh = josh.getHeight + '%';
    $('#daniel').height($daniel);
    $('#boaz').height($boaz);
    $('#josh').height($josh);
});
```

basically all this code does is creates three different `person` with different point levels, and then sets their heights according to the percent value compared to the person with the highest score. E.G. I have ten points and you have three points, I would be 100 and  you would be 3. I then use jQuery to convert this to % and try to resize the individual ids according to the percentage.

For some reason nothing is showing up when I do this on the actual page. What is going wrong? I am assuming that it has something to do with the jQuery, as the normal javascript is doing fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var scores = [daniel.height, boaz.height, josh.height],
```

should be

```
var scores = [daniel.points, boaz.points, josh.points],
```

Right?

And since you use `%`, so

```
this.height = String(this.points / highest);
```

should be

```
this.height = this.points / highest * 100;
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Renamed some things and I guess I never changed that. Thanks! but it still didn't work haha

Comment: @bob And you have to `* 100` for using `%`

Comment: Wait, this did fix it. Thank you so much! I'll need to look my code over closer next time...

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

`$boaz = boaz.getHeigt() + '%'`

which should be:

`$boaz = boaz.getHeight() + '%'`

Comment: Wow. messing up today. Thanks. But that still doesn't fix it.